# juego de memoria en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Soy  nuevo en el tema de desarrollo web y la verdad quiero hacer un juego de memoria, he visto uno que otro tutorial  pero están con Jquey del cual aún no se muy bien puesto que apenas comienzo con javascript, la cuestión es que no logro hacer que aparezca solo una pareja de imágenes, tengo la función que hace que por cada recarga las imágenes se ubiquen en un cuadro diferente, pero no logro realizar la función que haga que solo me aparezcan dos de cada imagen... 
aquí está lo que tengo hecho...

```
var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imagenes = ['ariel.jpg', 'bella.jpg', 'bestia.jpg', 'blanca.jpg', 'cenicienta.jpg', 'dana.jpg', 'jazmin.jpg', 'rapuncel.jpg'];

function numeroAleatorio(max, min) {
  var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) - min);
  return aleatorio;
}

function rotarFichas() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgTags.length; i++) {
    imgTags[i].src = imagenes[numeroAleatorio(imagenes.length - 1, 0)];
  }
}
window.onload = rotarFichas;
```

Comment: Pero la idea es que el usuario haga click y se muestre una imagen, luego haga otro click en otra imagen se vean las dos??

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que cargues un array con todas las parejas de imagenes que quieras tener y luego lo desordenes.

Comment: si es buena idea pero igual el indice del arreglo es un numero aleatorio el cual puede ser el mismo mas de tres veces lo cual  no sería lo que busco

Comment: Deberías para compartir tu código para que pudiéramos ver hasta donde tienes hecho y como quieres hacerlo para poder mejor entender así tu idea y poderte ayudar de la mejor manera. Un saludo.

Comment: var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imagenes = ['ariel.jpg', 'bella.jpg', 'bestia.jpg', 'blanca.jpg', 'cenicienta.jpg', 'dana.jpg', 'jazmin.jpg', 'rapuncel.jpg'];

function numeroAleatorio(max, min) {
  var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) - min);
  return aleatorio;
}

function rotarFichas() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgTags.length; i++) {
    imgTags[i].src = imagenes[numeroAleatorio(imagenes.length - 1, 0)];
  }
}
window.onload = rotarFichas;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es un bucle que recorra cada una de las diferentes imágenes que tienes en el array. Una vez hecho esto, hacer otro bucle para recorrer el número máximo de veces que se puede repetir cada imagen.

Dentro del segundo bucle deberás comprobar que la etiqueta `<img>` aleatoria no tenga ya una imagen en su ruta. En caso de ser así, el programa deberá generar otra posición aleatoria hasta que encuentre una etiqueta `<img>` que no tenga ninguna imagen asignada.

Ejemplo:

```js
var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imagenes = ["http://arcdn02.mundotkm.com/2014/05/BELLA.jpg", "http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/d3/Bestia.png/revision/latest?cb=20120926141704&path-prefix=es", "http://www.imagexia.com/img/Ariel-La-sirenita.jpg"];

var posicionAleatoria;
var numMaximoRepetido = 2;

function numeroAleatorio(max, min) {
  var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) - min);
  return aleatorio;
}

function rotarFichas() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < numMaximoRepetido; j++){
      posicionAleatoria = numeroAleatorio(imgTags.length - 1, 0);
      while(imgTags[posicionAleatoria].src != ""){
        posicionAleatoria = numeroAleatorio(imgTags.length - 1, 0);
      }
      imgTags[posicionAleatoria].src = imagenes[i];
    }
  }
}

window.onload = rotarFichas;
```

```css
img{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<img>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo voy a probar a ver si me funciona.

Comment: @user22090 De nada! Es un placer :)

Answer (score 1):

Este código puede ayudarte a entender un poco de la logica que requiere este juego para su implementan. Puedes copiarlo en un .html y correrlo para que veas.

```js
var cnt = 0;
var last;

window.addEventListener('load', main);

function main() {

  var list = document.querySelectorAll('div[cl^="card"]');

  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    list[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if(this.className == 'cardBlack') {
        this.className = this.getAttribute('cl');
        if(cnt == 1)
          if(last.className == this.className) {
            alert("OK");
          } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
              last.className = this.className = "cardBlack";
            }.bind(this), 500);
          }
        else
          last = this;
        cnt = 1 - cnt;
      }
    }, false);

}
```

```css
#cardList {

  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;

}

div[cl^="card"] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.cardBlack {
  background-color: #000;
}

div.cardRed {
  background-color: #f00;
}

div.cardBlue {
  background-color: #00f;
}

div.cardGreen {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cardList">
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardRed"></div>
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardBlue"></div>
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardRed"></div>
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardGreen"></div>
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardBlue"></div>
  <div class="cardBlack" cl="cardGreen"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: La pregunta estaba orientada a cómo mezclar las fichas. En tu ejemplo se están usando siempre en el mismo lugar. No veo cómo esto responde a la pregunta.